# AppleScript get value of a button

Tags: applescript, ui

I want to get the value of a button from an internal tool.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "App"
    set myNumberIs to get value of radio group 1 of group 1 of splitter ¬
       group 1 of window "my app" of application process "my app process"
end tell
```

return:

```
radio button " (1)" of radio group 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of ¬
   window "my app"
```

How can I save the `1` as a value?

I tried text trimming but that didn't work. Also tried to do something like this:

```
if myNumberIs contains " (1)" then set myNumberIsAsInteger to 1
```

but then I get an error:

```
System Events got an error: Can’t get result of radio button \...
```

Comment: Your first code snippet does not compile as the `tell application` block is not closed.  Can you paste the rest of the code ?  Right now, I'm confused how the `value` of a `radio group` object can return a `radio button` object.  This implies to me that either the code is incomplete, or I'm too tired to compute what's actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code with "Notifications" and found that "get value" actually returns the ***"AXTitle"*** of button "Notifications" – *NOT its "AXValue"*.

Therefore you must code:

```
if title of myNumberIs contains " (1)" then set myNumberIsAsInteger to 1
```

This works fine with me …